Database button is not appearing in the pgadmin4 interface

The database option does not appear under servers.
I deleted it and reinstalled it but it did not work. I wrote a few codes via cmd but it did not work
While the application was being installed, I wrote postgres for the username but when I wrote the same in the password section, it entered and I could not create a password myself.

I would it is because you have not actually created a Server yet. Click on Add New server and create the pgAdmin4 server entry. It is detailed in the docs Connecting to server.

Also you have to install postgres - pgadmin4 is a db client

Teşekkür ederim. Onu da yaptım ama olmadı bende 15.8 versiyonu indirdim,Database Server paketini de indirince düzeldi.
